# Unity - Its is saying its doesn't have a definition for the variable when it is a parameter for a funcition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is saying it does not have a definition for the variable when I defined it in the parameter
I tried to set args to an Event Handler using a function so I don't have to repeat myself and it will be more clearer.

This is the function:

```
private void SetSelectedCounter(ClearCounter ParameterSelectedCounter) {
        this.ParameterSelectedCounter = SelectedCounter;
            
        if(OnSelcetedCounterChanged != null) {
                
          OnSelcetedCounterChanged(this, new OnSelcetedCounterChangedEventArgs {
          SelcetedCounter = SelectedCounter
          });
       }
    }
```

Comment: which of the 2 lines does it complain about?   line 2? please read [mcve] we dont know where you defined SelectCounter

Comment: Umm Sorry, I defined SelectedCounter above inside the player class which this function also inside. It complains about line 2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, where to start? First, you need to post the full error message, don't interpret it for us, don't translate it for us, don't tell us what you *think* it means. Just copy paste it, trust us, we can understand it too and if we have questions, we will ask. So please, in the meantime, post the **exact** error message with the callstack.

Moving on, let's take it one at a time. This is going to be a blind analysis because of your incomplete question, so bear with me.

Here we go!

```
private void SetSelectedCounter(ClearCounterParameterSelectedCounter) {
```

What is `ClearCounterParameterSelectedCounter`? A type name? A parameter name? C# doesn't allow anonymous params like C does (and even there I am totally against it).

I assume you mean

```
private void SetSelectedCounter(ClearCounterParameter SelectedCounter)
```

Next:

```
    this.ParameterSelectedCounter = SelectedCounter;
```

Why are you using `this`? Is there another `ParameterSelectedCounter` defined somewhere else? If so, why? if not, why are you using `this`? :)

```
    if(OnSelcetedCounterChanged != null) {
```

`OnSelcetedCounterChanged` or do you mean `OnSelECtedCounterChanged` ?

```
      OnSelcetedCounterChanged(this, new OnSelcetedCounterChangedEventArgs
```

`OnSelcetedCounterChangedEventArgs` or do you mean `OnSelECtedCounterChangedEventArgs` ?

```
      SelcetedCounter = SelectedCounter
```

I think you mean `SelECtedCounter` instead of `SelCEtedCounter`, but then it would just be `SelectedCounter = SelectedCounter` so this line is a mystery to me. Please explain it.

When you write code, it is not just about writing code. You also need good code design, optimizations, good function / var / param names and most importantly: proof reading. A badly written word can make a (bad) difference. Imagine writing a game about making a restaurant in the desert. Or is it dessert? Or are they both correct? And if they are both correct, in what context? :)

Also imagine that one day someone else will re-read your code (even if it won't happen). And trust me, even you, 10 years from now, might have problems with it if you don't properly scan it for all types of errors and ambiguities.

Let me know if this fixed your error, if not, I am waiting for the error message.